# CSS background image URL

Tags: css

I want to insert an image in CSS bubble, the code is correct but nothing appears, 
can you please check how to solve this one

```
.triangle-isosceles {
        position: relative;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 1em 0 3em;
        color: #000;
        background: #f3961c;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        /*border-radius: 10px;*/
        background: linear-gradient(top, #f9d835, #f3961c);
    }
```

now before

```
.triangle-isosceles:before {
        content: "";
        display: block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -15px;
        left: 50px;
        width: 0;
        border-width: 15px 15px 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #f3961c transparent;
    }
```

the last one is after

```
.triangle-isosceles:after{
        content: url("/web/resources/images/paul.png");
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -130px;
        left: 12px;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        border:0;
        background: #3365d4;
        -moz-border-radius: 70px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
        border-radius: 70px;

              }
```

Comment: Is the image URL definitely correct in relation to your .css file?

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: Or i need to change the path Url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "after" version, you have two errors:

- **content:** This is not the correct tag to specify the background, the correct one would be simply "background"
- **background:** As you may figure by reading the first error, the background property you have defined is the one who is specifiying the background. This tag has to be removed as it will be overwritten if is not deleted.

So the CSS should loke like this:

```
.triangle-isosceles:after {
    background: url("/web/resources/images/paul.png");
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -130px;
    left: 12px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border:0;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
```

You should also consider to add compatibility with more browsers. You can find more information at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

**EDIT**: This is an example of a working CSS tag that add a background image to a "div":

```
#headerwrap {
    background: url(../images/homepage/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I already deleted the content, with the background, and now nothing appears, the bubble doesn't seen any  more

Comment: Does the web console throw any erros? Right click on your page (at the browser) -> Inspect element -> At the now options shown, choose from the top menu the "Console" option.

Comment: I know the problem is related in Symfony so we need to use assetic URL in content , the result must be : content: url("{{ asset('resources/images/Paul.png') }}");

Comment: This is an example of what you may want to achieve that I've used in one of my projects. This simpli set a background image of a div. you can find the CSS in the following link [https://ghostbin.com/paste/gbn84](https://ghostbin.com/paste/gbn84). Hope it helps

Comment: Updated my answer with the working example I post in the URL below. If the code was usefull for you to solve your problem, feel free to mark mi answer as the correct one =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add content also, Without content after and before won't work

Like this :

```
.triangle-isosceles:after {
    content :'';
    background: url("/web/resources/images/paul.png");
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -130px;
    left: 12px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border:0;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I think it's the problem that Symfony don't understand URL background

Comment: No, it doesn't work, but i do use content URL with assetic because I use Symfony as framework, otherwise thank you for your help :)